# Unittesting - Doing it wrong for plugins?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I am unittesting my cakephp-plugins. However, I got this situation.
My plugin-tests works well, but when I activate another plugin (who's fixtures (tables) are not loaded, my original tests won't pass anymore!

How to 'fix' this? Is it the responsibility for the second plugin who let the other tests fail, or do I have to prepare myself in my main-plugin for situations like this?

Hopefully I described the situation clear...

#### EDIT

Lets make it clear :)

I have tested a controller in plugin 'A'. It passes all tests so thats great.
But, when I load plugin 'B' in my system and I test the samen controller from plugin 'A' it fails because plugin 'B' wants a specific table who doesn't exist because my test didn't load it's fixture.

This gave me the question: How do i have to test? Should I only focus on plugin 'A' our keep in mind that plugin 'B' could possibly join the system (which is very complicated)...

Greetz

Comment: "Won't work" is not an appropriate error description.

Comment: Give me a suggestion... Pass?

Comment: Error message? Stack trace? Notice?

Comment: "_Won't pass_" won't do it either, there are like 1.000.000.001 possible reasons for the tests failing, so what is needed is a proper description of _what_ exactly is failing _how_ exactly.

Comment: _"but when I activate another plugin (who's fixtures (tables) are not loaded"_... Seems clear enough....

Comment: Edited my question, I hope its better?

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to test your plugins in isolation, that means to only install plugin A and run its tests and in another place install plugin B and run its tests.

If you are affecting plugin A from plugin B so that tests fail you will need to fix your tests to account for those cases if you want all tests to be ran in the same test suite.